# Custom Leaflet map in MediaWiki

Tags: leaflet, mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions

so i build a custom Leaflet map and I would like to integrate it into my Wiki. I tried both the Kartographer and the Maps extension, but for both I can't find how to feed them the url of my map.
Is this even possible?
If there is such an option in either of these extensions or another extension I have overlooked please let me know.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out the same thing. The Maps extension should have this somewhere, but I haven't found it yet.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible now (May 2020) with the Maps extension

So you can add this to a wiki page

```
{{#display_map: 
| image layers=mymap.jpg 
| geojson=MyMap
}}
```

Then create a page in the GeoJson namespace called `GeoJson:MyMap` to match the param you passed to `display_map`

Now the map has editable GeoJson data in the wiki and on the GeoJson: namespace page

Now you have a map with GeoJson data that you can add for markers etc

Not all of leaflet's options are available as of yet in mediawiki Maps extension - but a few are - they can be seen by adding the following to a page:

```
{{#mapsdoc:leaflet|parameters=all}}
```

Finally there is the maps documentation [Maps for MediaWiki Docs](https://maps.extension.wiki/wiki/Maps_for_MediaWiki)